# How to save new user data to Firebase Realtime Database after Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have written a function to write new user data if needed to database like this

```
private void writeNewUserIfNeeded(final String userId, final String username, final String name) {
    final DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");

    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(userId))
                usersRef.child(userId).setValue(new User(username, name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

But the problem is the `onDataChange` never called eventhough the function is called, so I cannot save my new user data. How is the best practice to save the new data?

**UPDATE: Add Rules**
And this is the rules I wrote

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix the problem.
Only need add child of the `UID`

```
private void writeNewUserIfNeeded(final String userId, final String username, final String name) {
    final DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId);

    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists())
                usersRef.setValue(new User(username, name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use addChileEventListener, here is the example

```
 usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for (DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


            }
            UserModel users=dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            items.add(users);
            adapter=new CutomAdapter(items,ListShow.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: I just want to save the data like `name` and `username` after log in, so I don't have to populate it on list view.

Comment: That was just an example. You can do whatever you want.